# pgfplots + animate: complicated line-by-line animation

Tags: pgfplots, animate

I want a retangle with 80 diagonal lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%------------------------
%% Options
%------------------------
    width= 100mm,
    %height = 50mm,
    xmax=70,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=50,
    ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits
]
%------------------------
%% Define Clipping
%------------------------
\pgfplotsextra{%
    \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);
    % http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22837&start=0
}   
%------------------------    
%% Loop
%------------------------
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,80} {
\addplot[
domain=0:60,
line width=1pt,
]
  {4/6*x+40-\i}; 
}
%------------------------
%% Draw retangle
%------------------------
\draw[red,line width=2pt] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);  
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I have a data file that looks like

```
4, % Line 1 is the top left corner
5,
50,
51,
52,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
22,
...
```

Now I want that the 80 lines appear in a animate animation in that order line-by-line. I made a animated gif manually to show the desired output:

[image]

But from here I do not have the right idea to proceed.

**Solution from Jake**

Thanks for the answers! I accept Jake's answer because it uses an external file which is important for me. My real example hat over 1200 lines. Here's the solution (Jake's answer is missing the filecontents envoronment):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{index.dat}
4,
5,
50,
51,
52,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
22,
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\indextable

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{2}
\multiframe{11}{imax=0+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%------------------------
%% Options
%------------------------
    width= 100mm,
    %height = 50mm,
    xmax=70,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=50,
    ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits
]
%------------------------
%% Define Clipping
%------------------------

\pgfplotsextra{%
    \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);
    % http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22837&start=0
}   
%------------------------    
%% Loop
%------------------------

\foreach\i in {0,...,\imax}{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\indextable}
\edef\currentindex{\pgfplotsretval}
\addplot[
domain=0:60,
line width=1pt,
]
  {4/6*x+40-\currentindex};
}

%------------------------
%% Draw retangle
%------------------------
\draw[red,line width=2pt] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);  
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the data file containing the ordered values into a PGFPlots table macro and then loop over that within the `animateinline` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\indextable

\begin{animateinline}{2}
\multiframe{10}{imax=0+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%------------------------
%% Options
%------------------------
    width= 100mm,
    %height = 50mm,
    xmax=70,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=50,
    ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits
]
%------------------------
%% Define Clipping
%------------------------
\pgfplotsextra{%
    \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);
    % http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22837&start=0
}   
%------------------------    
%% Loop
%------------------------

\foreach\i in {0,...,\imax}{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\indextable}
\edef\currentindex{\pgfplotsretval}
\addplot[
domain=0:60,
line width=1pt,
]
  {4/6*x+40-\currentindex};
}




%------------------------
%% Draw retangle
%------------------------
\draw[red,line width=2pt] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);  
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. Is the \edef important? Or could I use \newcommand?

Answer (score 4):

This works with beamer. The loop is outside `axis`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

  \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [count=\j] in  {4,5,50,51,52,6,7} {
\begin{axis}[
%------------------------
%% Options
%------------------------
    width= 100mm,
    %height = 50mm,
    xmax=70,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=50,
    ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits
]
%------------------------
%% Define Clipping
%------------------------
\pgfplotsextra{%
    \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);
    % http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22837&start=0
}   
%------------------------
%% Draw retangle
%------------------------
\draw[red,line width=2pt] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);  

\addplot[
domain=0:60,
line width=1pt, visible on=<\j->] 
  {4/6*x+40-\i}; 
\end{axis}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Later I'll made a gif and add some more information.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great - thanks. Can you expand it so that I can use an external file with the line order? Using it in Beamer is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt where the list of order can be changed for more flexibility. `App` is a command that takes two arguments #1= # of frames and #2= the order of line drawing. Be aware that the  #1 in `\multiframe{#1}` should be the last in the `App` list.

The `App` command itself is a whiledo loop that draw off-diagonal lines.

Please cut and paste to show the animation take places.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{01}
\newcommand{\App}[2]{
\whiledo{\value{n}=#1 \and \icount=#1}{
 \stepcounter{n}            % #1= # of frame
     \foreach \i in {#2} {  % #2=list
\addplot[
domain=0:60,
line width=1pt,
]
  {4/6*x+40-\i}; 
}}}


\begin{document}
%\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,poster =first, controls]{1}
\multiframe{10}{icount=0+1}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%------------------------
%% Options
%------------------------
    width= 100mm,
    %height = 50mm,
    xmax=70,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=50,
    ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits
]
%------------------------
%% Define Clipping
%------------------------
\pgfplotsextra{%
    \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);
    % http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22837&start=0
}   
%------------------------    
%% Loop
%------------------------
\App{1}{4}
\App{2}{4,5}
\App{3}{4,5,50}
\App{4}{4,5,50,51}
\App{5}{4,5,50,51,52}
\App{6}{4,5,50,51,52,6}
\App{7}{4,5,50,51,52,6,7,8}
\App{8}{4,5,50,51,52,6,7,8,9}
\App{9}{4,5,50,51,52,6,7,8,9,10}
\App{10}{4,5,50,51,52,6,7,8,9,10,22}
%------------------------
%% Draw retangle
%------------------------
\draw[red,line width=2pt] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:60,40);  
\end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The \App approach is not useful when I have a huge amount of lines. But I like the idea and will use it together with other problems!

Comment: Ya, I understand. Just trying to help out.